# Writing an analytic function to mark last date of some column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, row-number

Can you help me to write an analytic function that marks the last date a client's service was stopped. For example one client has 2-3 stops of his service, and I would like to count how many stops there are, and to mark last date of stopping.

I'm using

```
SELECT column_name1, column_name2, column_name3, column_name4
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column_name3 ORDER BY column_name4) AS Something 
  FROM ... 
 WHERE ...
 ORDER B
```

where `column_name3` contains status - is service stopped, and `column_name4` contains date of last stop.

Comment: Thank you for editing. My English isn't very good. In column_name3 there are 'active', 'inactive'. column_name4 contains dates - which date in column_name3 became active or inactive

Comment: What column identifies the client?

Comment: column 1 is identity number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly

```
select unique column_name1, column_name2, column_name3,
    max(when column_name3 = 'inactive' then column_name4 end) over(partition by column_name1) last_date,
    count(when column_name3 = 'inactive' then 1 end) over(partition by column_name1) cnt
```